# Is it a security flaw if a cookie that determines if someone was logged in is accessible in the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently doing the rails tutorial available at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/

Somewhere around chapter 7-8 I had an error while deploying to Heroku (I unfortunately forget the error) but I found the solution online was to make the remember_token variable accessible in the user model. I wasn't sure if the solution was legit or not, but it worked, so I had no problem continuing the tutorial.

The remember_token is a variable that is defined as below:

```
self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
```

In other words, it is a randomized string of characters, so in and of itself, it is pretty safe. I.e. no one could just guess it.

It is used with a cookie to determine if someone was previously logged in:

```
def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
end

def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
end

def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end
```

However my user model has the following:

```
attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_token
```

...and I'm wondering if this remember_token as an accessible attribute would be a security flaw. Can someone just theoretically use a client command line and obtain the remember_token with something like `user.remember_token` ? Once they have the remember_token, couldn't they just simulate being previously logged in and thus no password / email combination would be necessary? Can someone with a bit more experience please shed some light on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

attr_accessible makes the column updateable via mass assignment.

Therefore, allowing it on remember_token means they could theoretically hack up a new POST-form for user#update and set it to whatever they pass in through the form.

However, I don't *think* that what you are suggesting is possible.
What kind of console could somebody use to give the user access to your models?

To get that kind of access they'd have to be running the console on your server, in your Rails root... which is unlikely.

It's unlikely that a person can access the remember_token of *another* user, unless you let other users access the details of other users (ie not their own user), via controller actions. Allowing access to a user's own remember_token shouldn't matter - they already have it.